# Unable to show date picker from top to bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker

I have created a custom datepicker. I want to show this from bottom to top.but it is not showing it is showing from top to bottom.

Here is the code.

```
let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
        self.datePicker = CustomDatePicker.instanceFromNib(frame: frame) as? CustomDatePicker
        self.datePicker?.configureDatePicker()
        datePicker?.customPickerDelegate = self
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {

            DILog.print(items: "Updated Y is \(self.view.frame.height - self.view.frame.height/3)")
            let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
            self.datePicker = CustomDatePicker.instanceFromNib(frame: frame) as? CustomDatePicker

        }, completion: { (value) in

        })
        self.view.addSubview(self.datePicker!)
```

Comment: How you could you expect animation on UIView which is not subview yet ? Should be closed

Comment: It is simple one line solution remove  self.datePicker = Custo... from Animation block and set frame directly and before you execute animation just add subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to animate picker must be added before animation , second you must not load the picker from nib again inside the animation

```
         let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
         self.datePicker = CustomDatePicker.instanceFromNib(frame: frame) as? CustomDatePicker

        self.datePicker?.configureDatePicker()
        datePicker?.customPickerDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.datePicker!)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {

            DILog.print(items: "Updated Y is \(self.view.frame.height - self.view.frame.height/3)")

            self.datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)

        }, completion: { (value) in

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** : Add datePicker in parent view before animating. Unless you do that, it won't be visible.
**Second** : Your picker's y is not dynamic in the animation block. It should be **original y - height of picker**.

Overall code :

```
let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
self.datePicker = CustomDatePicker.instanceFromNib(frame: frame) as? CustomDatePicker
self.datePicker?.configureDatePicker()
datePicker?.customPickerDelegate = self
self.view.addSubview(self.datePicker!)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {

    DILog.print(items: "Updated Y is \(self.view.frame.height -        self.view.frame.height/3)")
    let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600 - self.view.frame.height/3, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
    self.datePicker = CustomDatePicker.instanceFromNib(frame: frame) as? CustomDatePicker

        }, completion: { (value) in

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

With some cool animation you can do the following...

```
 //configure date picker and add it

//animate it in this way
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

        self.datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)

    }) { (isDone) in

    }
```